# Error: ; expected, but where?

Tags: java

I'm trying to incorporate and if-else statement in a program but I keep getting an "error: ';' expected" message. However, even if I add the ;, it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IdealWeight
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int OVERMEN = 6;
        final int OVERFEMALE = 5;
        final int INCHESINFOOT = 12;

        int feet;
        int inches;
        int totalHeight;
        int idealWeightMale;
        int idealWeightFemale;

        double leewayMale;
        double leewayFemale;
        double minIdealWeightFemale;
        double maxIdealWeightFemale;
        double minIdealWeightMale;
        double maxIdealWeightMale;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Consider your height in imperial units. Break it up into feet and inches.");
        System.out.println("Enter your height in feet.");

        feet = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the remaining inches."); 

        inches = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You entered your height as: " + feet + " feet " + inches + " inches");

        totalHeight = (feet * INCHESINFOOT) + inches;

        if (60 > totalHeight)
            {
            idealWeightFemale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE));
            idealWeightMale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERMALE));
            }
        else
            {
            idealWeightFemale = (100 + (inches * OVERFEMALE));
            idealWeightMale = (100 + (inches * OVERMEN));
            }

        System.out.println("If you are female, your ideal weight is " + idealWeightFemale + " pounds.");
        System.out.println("If you are male, your ideal weight is " + idealWeightMale + " pounds.");    

        leewayMale = (.15 * idealWeightMale);   
        leewayFemale = (.15 * idealWeightFemale);
        minIdealWeightMale = (idealWeightMale - leewayMale);
        maxIdealWeightMale = (idealWeightMale + leewayMale);
        minIdealWeightFemale = (idealWeightFemale - leewayFemale);
        maxIdealWeightFemale = (idealWeightFemale + leewayFemale);

        System.out.println("However, if you are male and are within " + minIdealWeightMale + " and " + maxIdealWeightMale + " you are at a healthy weight.");
        System.out.println("However, if you are female and are within " + minIdealWeightFemale + " and " + maxIdealWeightFemale + " you are at a healthy weight.");


    }
}
```

The goal is to make this is to make it work with people under 5 feet without changing anything else. Here is the error message:

```
    IdealWeight.java:47: error: ';' expected
            idealWeightFemale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE));
                                                                                ^
IdealWeight.java:48: error: ';' expected
            idealWeightMale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERMALE));
                                                                            ^
```

Comment: there is 1 extra Paranthesis is added in your statement at end ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra ")" in this line

```
idealWeightFemale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE));
```

Change it to

```
idealWeightFemale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE);
```

Similar for `idealWeightMale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERMALE));`

Comment: @Abu if it solves OP's problem, then it's an answer :). I learned that when answering OP with comments and losing rep.

Comment: Yes, three answers for that question... people are really hungry :-(

Comment: @ring0 there are simple questions with 7 or more answers.

Answer (score 0):

`((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE))` you have an extra end bracket`)` here and in the next line. Change that to `((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE)` and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

try with following code

`idealWeightFemale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERFEMALE);`

`idealWeightMale = ((100 * totalHeight)/60) + (inches * OVERMALE);`